# pytables - how to copy a row to memory

Tags: python, pytables

I have a pytable. I often need to copy the rows to an in-memory object and then insert into another pytable. I am wondering what is the easiest way to do this. The following code does not work as one cannot convert a Row object to a dict.

```
for row in hf.root.my_table.iterrows():
   rec = dict(row)
```

Also, I want to conditionally copy the data to another file, possibly adding 1-2 new columns.To do this, I will need to extract the table description from one table, modify it, and use the modified table description to create a new table. How can I do that?

This won't work either. In general, I find my way of using pytables a little bit awkward, and would like to know better way of doing things.

Comment: As far as copying is concerned, aren't the rows already in an in-memory object? I don't use Pytables so I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: I am not very sure myself, but I think although the Row object is in-memory, it is attached to the underlying table object, and so the contents can be modified if I move the current position or change the table. So I don't think it is suitable to store the Row object into other objects for the purpose of keeping the contents for later reference.

Comment: I think what you want to do is get the data from the row as a numpy rec array which should be possible with row[:]. The resulting array you can then do what ever you like with it and if you like append it to another table

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#tables.tableextension.Row.fetch_all_fields), you can use the `Row.fetch_all_fields` method to obtain to obtain an independent copy which retains its information after the table file is closed, for example.

Your example code would look like

```
for row in hf.root.my_table.iterrows():
    rec = row.fetch_all_fields()
```

`rec` is a numpy void scalar with the same keys as the row; `rec['field']` yields the same data as `row['field']`.